# TSP 200-approximation, given $c(x,z)\le c(x,y) + 100\cdot c(y,z)$ for all nodes $x,y,z$

Tags: complexity-theory, approximation, traveling-salesman

Input: complete, undirected graph $G=(V,E)$ and cost function $c$
Assume for all nodes $x,y,z \in V$:  $c(x,z)\le c(x,y) + 100\cdot c(y,z)$

Find a 200-approximation polynomial time algorithm for the input.

I've seen the regular 2-approximation algorithm for a graph that satisfies the triangle inequality.

1. Find the MST $T$ for the graph
2. Find Euler Cycle by doubling the edges in $T$
3. Find Hamiltonian Cycle by removing each vertex that appears more than once

If $c(x,z)\le c(x,y) + 100\cdot c(y,z)$ , then $c(x,z)\le c(x,y) + c(y,z)$ , so I figure we can use the same approximation algorithm. But I'm not sure how to prove that this gives a 200-approximation.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true.

> If $c(x,z)\le c(x,y) + 100\cdot c(y,z)$ , then $c(x,z)\le c(x,y) + c(y,z)$

However it is true that, for $x,z \in V$ with $x \neq z$, you have $c(x,z) \le 100 d(x,z)$.
To see this let $P$ be a shortest path from $x$ to $z$. The proof is by induction on the number of edges $|P|$ of $P$.

If $|P|=1$ then $c(x,z) = d(x,z) \le 100 d(x,z)$.

If $|P| \ge 2$ then, let $y$ be the vertex immediately preceding $z$ in $P$.
By inductive hypothesis $c(x, y) \le 100 d(x,y)$ and you have
$$
c(x,z) \le c(x,y) + 100 c(y,z) \le  100 d(x,y) + 100 c(y,z) =100 d(x,z). \quad \square
$$

Consider a MST $M$ of $G$ and let $T$ be a Euler tour of $M$, starting from an arbitrary vertex.
Let $v_0, v_1, \dots, v_{n-1}$ be the vertices in $V$ in the order they appear for the first time in $T$ and let $v_n = v_0$. Consider the tour $T'$ that visits $v_0, v_1, \dots, v_n$ in this order.

For $i=0, \dots, n-1$ let $T_i$ be the portion of the tour between the first occurrence of $v_i$ in $T$ and the next occurrence of $v_{i+1}$ in $T$.
Given any graph $H$, let $c(H)$ be the sum of costs of the edges in $H$.
Let $T^*$ an optimal tour of $G$.

You have:
$$
\begin{align*}
c(T') &= \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} c(v_i, v_{i+1}) \le 100 \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} d(v_i, v_{i+1}) \le 100 \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} c(T_i) \\
&\le 100 c(T) \le 200 c(M) \le 200 c(T^*). 
\end{align*}
$$